# Parted automatically adding a filesystem on mkpart

Tags: linux, partition, parted

I created an ext4 file system on /dev/sda1 yesterday to test the drive before trying to add it to a RAID.  It's a 3 TB drive, so I'm trying to use parted to do all my partition stuff.

I've done an `rm 1` and then `print` shows no partitions.  If I then do `mkpart primary 0% 100%` (no file system specified), and then do `print` it shows the partition with an ext4 file system.

How can I remove the partition so that it also then removes the file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parted didn't automatically create a filesystem; you created it.

When you deleted the partition, that's the only thing you deleted. Deleting the partition doesn't delete any of the data within the partition, so there's still a valid ext4 filesystem there. Thus, when you recreate the partition and `print` the partition table, it can be clearly seen.

To resolve the issue, [erase the hard drive](https://serverfault.com/q/56280/126632) or the partition, or simply create a new filesystem on the partition.

Comment: What should I do to "erase the hard drive"?  I've tried doing a `mklabel` to over write everything, but even that didn't solve it.

Comment: [Fastest, surest way to erase a hard drive?](http://serverfault.com/q/56280/126632)

Comment: So just for clarification, the partition did go away, but since I created over the same space, all of that data that set up the file system was still intact?

Comment: Right, you only deleted the partition, not any of the data within it.

Comment: Works for me.  `dd`ing right now.