# How to securely erase damaged hard drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, advanced-format

I have a few hard drives with bad sectors and I want to securely erase all the data from there before I throw the drives away.

It's pretty easy even in Windows to format a regular harddrive, and I can do multipass from the command line. But when the drive has bad sectors then the format fails.

Most Google searches returns helps on how to recover the data or 'fix' the drive.

What tools to use to just wipe the drive?

Comment: `What tools to use to just wipe the drive?` A bench vise and 7" grinder should to the trick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest, surest way to erase a hard drive?](https://serverfault.com/questions/56280/fastest-surest-way-to-erase-a-hard-drive)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend DBAN (https://dban.org/).  It's free.  You can load it to a flash drive and boot from that (https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-erase-a-hard-drive-using-dban-2619148), or burn it to a cd if your BIOS are too old.  It has a few different options from a quick erase to a 35 pass overwrite.

After that I'd recommend something like what Greg said, perhaps a sledgehammer?