# Create random file with openssl

Tags: openssl, dd, cryptography, random-number-generator

So I read this question[Urandom Alternative](https://serverfault.com/questions/6440/is-there-an-alternative-to-dev-urandom), but I am unable to make a comment there (without 50 rep) - therefore I open a separate question:
If I use this command instead of dd and urandom, how do I set the size of the resulting randomfile.bin?

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt < /dev/zero > randomfile.bin
```

Comment: You can't comment on that question because it is locked, because it isn't an on-topic question for this site.  Neither is this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading from `/dev/zero` that will generate infinity zeros, a way to limit it is using `head` command to control the size of the output, and pipe that instead of passing it as the input file. So a way to generate a 65535 file is the following:

```
head -c 65535 /dev/zero | openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt  > randomfile.bin
```

Comment: The thing is, I want to create a 100gb file, which is afterwards used as LUKS container. Thanks a lot, your solution worked out fine!